# Gravar Dados de Cadastro em um TXT

Tags: c++

Bom dia, sou novato em C++ e Estou com um trabalho de faculdade aonde estou tendo um problema para gravar os dados que recebo da função cadastro do meu código em um TXT e validar os dados na função Login. Alguém poderia me ajudar ou me dar dicas de uma possível solução.

Obrigado a todos que tentarem me ajudar.

Utilizei C++ e um pouco de C

Segue Meu Código.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#define SIZE 200
using namespace std;

char nome[SIZE][50];
char Sobrenome[SIZE][50];
char CNPJ[SIZE][50];
char razaosocial[SIZE][50];
char telefone[SIZE][50];
char email[SIZE][50];
char senha[SIZE][50];
char senhaacesso[SIZE][50];
char login[SIZE][50];
int opcao;

/* void cadastrosenha(); */
void cadastro(); // Chamando a função Login
void acesso();   // Chamando a função cadastro

int escolha() // Função de escolha para Login ou Cadastro
{
    int selecao;
    cout << "Selecione 1 para ir até a tela de Login" << endl;
    cout << endl;
  cout  << "selecione 2 para ir até a tela de cadastro" << endl;
    cin >> selecao;

    switch (selecao)
    {
    case 1:
        acesso();
        break;
    case 2:
        cadastro();
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}

void cadastro() // Função de cadastro
{
    FILE *pont_arq;

    pont_arq = fopen("Banco.txt", "w");
    if (pont_arq == NULL)
    {
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Erro na criação do arquivo" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    static int linha;
    cout << "Digite seu nome: " << endl;
    cin >> nome[linha];
    cout << "Digite seu Sobrenome: " << endl;
    cin >> Sobrenome[linha];
    cout << "Digite seu CNPJ: " << endl;
    cin >> CNPJ[linha];
    cout << "Digite sua razao social: " << endl;
    cin >> razaosocial[linha];
    cout << "Digite seu telefone: " << endl;
    cin >> telefone[linha];
    cout << "Digite seu Email: " << endl;
    cin >> email[linha];
    cout << "Digite sua senha" << endl;
    cin >> senhaacesso[linha];

    fprintf(pont_arq, "%s ", nome[linha], Sobrenome[linha], CNPJ[linha], razaosocial[linha], telefone[linha], email[linha], senhaacesso[linha]);

    cout << "\n\n";

    fclose(pont_arq);
    cout << "Dados salvos com sucesso" << endl;
    cout << "/n";
    if (opcao == 1)
    {
        cout << "Digite 1 para continuar ou outro valor para sair" << endl;
        cin >> opcao;
    }
    else
    {
        escolha();
    }
}

void acesso() // Função de acesso ao portal
{
    static int linha;
    cout << "Digite seu CNPJ: " << endl;
    cin >> CNPJ[linha];
    cout << "Digite seu Login" << endl;
    cin >> login[linha];
    cout << "Digite sua senha" << endl;
    cin >> senha[linha];

    if (opcao == 1)
    {
        cout << "Digite 1 para continuar ou outro valor para sair" << endl;
        cin >> opcao;
    }
    else
    {
        escolha();
    }
}

void cadastrosenha()
{
    if (senhaacesso == senha)
    {
        cout << "Senha bem vindo" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Senha incorreta, tente novamente ";
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    escolha();
    cadastro();
    acesso();
}
```

Comment: Vai ter trabalho para concluir assim. Não é um programa `C++`. Apenas código `C`  na prática. Seu programa trata um cadastro mas não tem um. Fica difícil. Escreva em torno de 1 cadastro ao menos. E não use `void` e funções sem argumentos. Só vai ficar mais difícil.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica mano, irei procurar melhorar nos pontos que você me indicou.

Answer (score -1):

Tem ainda muita coisa errada do modo como escreveu, mesmo para um programa C

Vou te mostrar algumas coisas e uma outra maneira de começar a escrever isso, em torno dos dados e não de um programa em qualquer linguagem.

#### Sobre o programa original

```
char nome[SIZE][50];
char Sobrenome[SIZE][50];
char CNPJ[SIZE][50];
char razaosocial[SIZE][50];
char telefone[SIZE][50];
char email[SIZE][50];
char senha[SIZE][50];
char senhaacesso[SIZE][50];
char login[SIZE][50];
```

Isso é um grupo de 9 vetores de vetores de `char[50]`, global em seu programa. Não é isso o que quer. Ao menos quase nunca é isso que quer.

```
struct Pessoa
{
    char nome[NAME_SIZE];
    char Sobrenome[NAME_SIZE];
    char CNPJ[NAME_SIZE];
    char razaosocial[NAME_SIZE];
    char telefone[NAME_SIZE];
    char email[NAME_SIZE];
    char login[NAME_SIZE];
    char senha[NAME_SIZE];

    void mostrar(const char* msg);
};
```

Isso acima é algo mínimo, mas entenda que isso é uma `Pessoa`, Uma abstração para um registro. Não cria nenhum, apenas define.

E considere

```
struct Cadastro
{
    size_t lim;      // capacidade
    size_t size;     // em uso
    Pessoa p[SIZE];  // o vetor

    // retorna o n. do usuario no cadastro ou -1
    int acessar(const char* login, const char* senha);
    // cadastra a Pessoa p no cadastro
    int cadastrar(Pessoa* p);
    // grava em 'arq' o cadastro
    int gravar(const char* arq);
    // mostra o cadastro na tela com um titulo opcional
    int mostrar(const char* msg);

    Cadastro();  // cria um cadastro vazio
    // le o cadastro a partir de 'arq'
    Cadastro(size_t size, const char* arq);
    // le os dados de 'arq' para o cadastro
    int ler(const char* arq);
};
```

Ainda não é muito `C++` mas dá pra ver o que é importante nesse caso: é um *container*. O `Cadastro` tem pessoas dentro. Num dado momento tem `size` pessoas e o limite é `lim`. Entenda como isso simplifica as coisas.

E as funções, chamadas aqui de métodos, tem a ver com o cadastro em que estão declaradas. E isso também simplifica muito as coisas. Veja no exemplo ao final.

#### Sobre `escolha()`

```
int escolha()  // Função de escolha para Login ou Cadastro
{
    int selecao;
    cout << "Selecione 1 para ir até a tela de Login"
         << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "selecione 2 para ir até a tela de cadastro"
         << endl;
    cin >> selecao;

    switch (selecao)
    {
        case 1:
            acesso();
            break;
        case 2:
            cadastro();
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Isso também raramente é o que quer. Não coloque a lógica do seu programa todo dentro de uma função que era pra retornar uma opção e se chama "escolha()`

Prefira algo assim

```
int escolha()
{
    int selecao;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "\
    Selecione:\n\
        0 - para encerrar\n\
        1 - para acessar a tela de Login\n\
        2 - para acessar a tela de cadastro\n\
\n\
     Sua opcao : ";

        cin >> selecao;
        if (selecao < 0) continue;
        if (selecao > 2) continue;
        return selecao;
    }
}
```

E entenda também que é bem melhor e dezenas de vezes mais rápido usar uma única chamada a `cout` , além de ficar mais fácil de alinhar o texto.

### Um exemplo

```
#define NAME_SIZE 50
#define SIZE 20
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Pessoa
{
    char nome[NAME_SIZE];
    char Sobrenome[NAME_SIZE];
    char CNPJ[NAME_SIZE];
    char razaosocial[NAME_SIZE];
    char telefone[NAME_SIZE];
    char email[NAME_SIZE];
    char login[NAME_SIZE];
    char senha[NAME_SIZE];

    void mostrar(const char* msg);
};

struct Cadastro
{
    size_t lim;      // capacidade
    size_t size;     // em uso
    Pessoa p[SIZE];  // o vetor

    // retorna o n. do usuario no cadastro ou -1
    int acessar(const char* login, const char* senha);
    // cadastra a Pessoa p no cadastro
    int cadastrar(Pessoa* p);
    // grava em 'arq' o cadastro
    int gravar(const char* arq);
    // mostra o cadastro na tela com um titulo opcional
    int mostrar(const char* msg);

    Cadastro();  // cria um cadastro vazio
    // le o cadastro a partir de 'arq'
    Cadastro(size_t size, const char* arq);
    // le os dados de 'arq' para o cadastro
    int ler(const char* arq);
};

int escolha();  // mostra o menu, retorna a opcao

int main(void)
{
    Cadastro cad;
    int      opcao = escolha();
    while (opcao != 0)
    {
        switch (opcao)
        {
            case 1:
                cad.acessar("usuario", "senha");
                break;
            case 2:
                cad.cadastrar(nullptr);
        }
        // acoes aqui
        opcao = escolha();
    }
    return 0;
}

int Cadastro::acessar(const char* login, const char* senha)
{
    cerr << "\n     ==> acessar(): Usuario \"" << login << "\" Senha \""
         << senha << "\"\n\n";
    return 0;
}

int Cadastro::cadastrar(Pessoa* pess)
{
    cerr << "\n    ==> cadastrar()\n\n";
    return 0;
}

int Cadastro::gravar(const char* arq) { return 0; }

int Cadastro::mostrar(const char* msg) { return 0; }

Cadastro::Cadastro() : Cadastro(SIZE, ""){};

Cadastro::Cadastro(size_t limite, const char* arq)
    : lim(limite), size(0)
{
    cerr << "Criado Cadastro. Capacidade " << lim
         << " Em uso: " << size << "\n\n\n";
}

int Cadastro::ler(const char* arq) { return 0; }

void Pessoa::mostrar(const char* msg) {}


int escolha()
{
    int selecao;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "\
    Selecione:\n\
        0 - para encerrar\n\
        1 - para acessar a tela de Login\n\
        2 - para acessar a tela de cadastro\n\
\n\
     Sua opcao : ";

        cin >> selecao;
        if (selecao < 0) continue;
        if (selecao > 2) continue;
        return selecao;
    }
}
```

Esse programa é o seu programa dentro do que eu expliquei. Já compila e já roda com sucesso. É muito mais simples escrever assim porque começa a testar em minutos e pode implementar as funções aos poucos.

#### Gravando dados no disco

Entenda que arquivos formatados como texto não são assim boas opções para "exportar" seus dados. O mais simples é gravar blocos de tamanho fixo com o conteúdo de cada registro do tal `Cadastro`. Usar funções de `C` como `fprintf()` vai levar a regisros de tamanho variável e nunca mais vai conseguir ler de volta isso.

De seu programa original

```
    fprintf(
        pont_arq, "%s ", nome[linha], Sobrenome[linha],
        CNPJ[linha], razaosocial[linha], telefone[linha],
        email[linha], senhaacesso[linha]);
```

Isso não faz sentido. Vai gravar uma única string? Como o compilador vai tratar isso? E era pra ser um loop? E os outros registros?

```
    static int linha;
```

porque isso? Para que serve linha? porque `static`

Entenda que esse site não encoraja esse tipo de respostas individualizadas para programas.

Comment: :) pois é: como eu disse *esse site não encoraja esse tipo de respostas individualizadas para programas*. Em poucos minutos minha resposta já foi considerada inútil por um atento usuário, apesar de ser uma resposta e orientada e contendo trechos de sua pergunta e código originais.

Comment: Te agradeço de mais pela resposta e dicas, irei verificar cada ponto que vc apontou a mim e estudar sobre para melhorar no próximo desafio! Muito Obrigado pela ajuda viu, qualquer duvida deixo aqui kkkk Mas eu gostei de mais da sua resposta e orientação, Obrigado novamente!